# Vector of pthread_mutex_t gives me the same address for all mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

I have this struct:

```
struct thread_items {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    int i;
    thread_items(pthread_mutex_t m, int i): mutex(m), i(i){}
}
```

I am trying to create an array of this struct and initialize all the mutexes while I am at it. For some reason, when I print the mutex addresses I get all the mutex's with the same address:

```
vector <thread_items*> thread_items_vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    thread_items * items = new thread_items(mutex, i);
    thread_items_vec.push_back(items);
    cout << "Mutex " << i << " is " << &mutex << endl;
}
```

This results with this print:

```
Mutex 0 is 0x7fff9580b520
Mutex 1 is 0x7fff9580b520
Mutex 2 is 0x7fff9580b520
```

The reason I got to print this is because my concurrency has issues and I noticed I am not locking the correct Mutex's.

So my question is do I initialize the mutex's correctly in order to have 3 different mutex's? Is my print really showing a problem here?
From the answers, I am printing the stack pointer which is always the same. Does this mean I am initializing my Mutex's for the same address?

Comment: What is `thread_items_map`?

Comment: What is thread_items_map ?

Comment: Sorry the code is really complex, I tried to bring only the relevant parts. I will edit my question

Comment: You show `thread_items` and `vector <thread_items>` but then create a `thread_items_map*` and add it to the vector. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic **especially [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: My bad, fixed it

Comment: In C++11 better use `std::mutex` instead of `pthread_mutex_t`

Comment: No you didn't fix it, because you're pushing `thread_items*` into a `vector<thread_items>`. I repeat, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the address of the stack variable `mutex`, this gets re-created each time round the loop presumably at the same address

Comment: So isn't that a problem when I do pthread_init_t(&mutex, NULL) ? Since I give the same address?

Comment: It's even worse `mutex` is destroyed each time round the loop.  You are passing the address to something that no-longer exists.

Comment: Your answer and comment helped me understand a bug that I was struggling with for too long. Even though my question got down voted, this was really worth it. Thank you sir.